# Kafka Connect - GET connector API exposes password in cleartext

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using the latest confluent images (5.1.0) and externalized OracleDB passwords for Connect configurations in vault. I am able to successfully register the custom config provider for vault with following configuration.

```
"connection.password": "${vault:vault_path:vault_db_password_key}"
```

When I do a GET connector request, the `connection.password` in the response is the resolved password and it is shown as such and was not hidden. But in logs, I could see it as

```
connection.password = [hidden]
```

Please let me know if this issue is handled as part of [KIP-297](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-297%3A+Externalizing+Secrets+for+Connect+Configurations) or if I am missing something?

Comment: c.f. https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/558

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but there is no such Credential provider for `vault:`, [by default, there is only `file:`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/config/provider), so unless you've written your own (or found one elsewhere), then that won't work.